# Getting error 'int' object has no attribute 'squeeze'?

Tags: python, pandas

when calling this `xyz= abcs(xyz)`

```
def abcs(df)
#some code

 def onedg(row):
    if row["dt1"]==row["dt2"]:
       return 1
    elif row["dt1"]>row["dt2"]:
        pass
    else:
        end_date=row["dt1"]
        start_date=row["dt2"]
        cumulative=[]
        cumulative = 1 
        while start_date<end_date:
            start_date += timedelta(days=1)
            ondf=dfx[dfx["Date"]==start_date]["X+Y+Z"].values
            cumulative= cumulative* ondf
      return cumulative.squeeze()
   df["fs"] = df.apply(lambda x: onedg(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: squeeze is used on arrays not on integers.

Comment: @Wimanicesir Can you suggest the solution or code changes for this ??

Comment: Why do you want to squeeze?